# Trying to scrape text from a site with BeautifulSoup4, but nothing happens at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from this website: https://playvalorant.com/en-us/news/game-updates/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

site_text = requests.get('https://playvalorant.com/en-us/news/game-updates/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(site_text, 'lxml')
posts = soup.find_all('li', class_="ContentListing-module--contentListingItem--3GAoa")
for post in posts:
    post_title = post.find(
        'h3', class_="heading-05 bold ContentListingCard-module--title--1vIFy").text
    post_title = post_title.lower()
    if "patch notes" in post_title:
        patch_ver = post_title.replace('valorant patch notes ', '')
        print(f'Patch version: {patch_ver}')
        print("")
```

But when I run it, nothing happens at all.

What I want to do is to see if the h3 includes the text "patch notes" and if so, check what version it is and go to https://playvalorant.com/en-us/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-(patch-number)-(patch-number)/ (for example, if the text was "VALORANT Patch Notes 3213.07", then I want to go to https://playvalorant.com/en-us/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3213-07, and so on.)

I'm  getting ahead of myself, but the point is, how can I get the text from this website, and then  print it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see is loaded via Javascript, sou BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can use `requests` module to simulate it:

```py
import json
import requests

url = (
    "https://playvalorant.com/page-data/en-us/news/game-updates/page-data.json"
)
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for a in data["result"]["pageContext"]["data"]["articles"]:
    if "Patch Notes" in a["title"]:
        patch_notes_url = "https://playvalorant.com" + a["url"]["url"]
        print("{:<30} {}".format(a["title"], patch_notes_url))
```

Prints:

```
VALORANT Patch Notes 4.04      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-4-04/
VALORANT Patch Notes 4.03      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-4-03/
VALORANT Patch Notes 4.02      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-4-02/
VALORANT Patch Notes 4.01      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-4-01/
VALORANT Patch Notes 4.0       https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-4-0/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.12      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-12/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.10      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-10/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.09      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-09/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.08      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-08/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.07      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-07/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.06      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-06/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.05      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-05/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.04      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-04/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.03      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-03/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.02      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-02/
VALORANT Patch Notes 3.01      https://playvalorant.com/news/game-updates/valorant-patch-notes-3-01/

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lxml to use xpath for accessing the required html nodes easily.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = "https://playvalorant.com/en-us/news/game-updates/"

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

posts = tree.xpath('//section[contains(@class, "section light")]/div/ul')
```